What is the purpose of the capacitor in this schematic? (Its the schematic of a 12V Fan Motor driver)
I found this circuit of a 12V electric fan of a computer.
I think I have understood how the circuit works besides the capacitor.

I found it here, via google: http://www.seekic.com/circuit_diagram/Amplifier_Circuit/the_computer_fan_circuit.html
Can anybody explain what the purpose of the capacitor is?
From my understanding a rough summary of this circuit is:
1.: The Hall-Sensor has two states ,dependent of the magnets of the motor:

Output driven to GND or
Output is high impedance (Like SS413 for example)

2.: If state 1 applies: The base of the left npn-transistor is tied to gnd, and blocks. Current flows through two coils and through the base of the right npn-transistor. Thus the a high current flows through the other two coils through the collector of the right transistor.
3.: If state 2 applies: The left npn-transistor does not block but is conductive. Base of right transistor is tied to gnd and blocks.  High current flows through the other two coils through collector of first transistor.
But what is the capacitor needed for?
(And did I get the circuit correct?)

The capacitor ensures that there is always path for current to flow through the coils.
When the transistor driving a pair of coils turns off, the current won't immediately decay to zero. Instead, the voltage across the coil will be proportional to the decay rate of the current. This voltage can be really high, and it's called "inductive kick" or "flyback voltage". The voltage is limited only by parasitic effects.
This inductive kick is how automotive ignition coils generate spark voltage :)
The capacitor allows the energy stored in the magnetic field of the coils to transfer between the coils. It forms an LC resonant circuit that incidentally also controls the switching action of the transistor for the 2nd coil. The capacitor can be selected so that the resonant frequency is 2x the angular frequency of rotation of the fan. It will then transfer the energy between the two coils, minimizing the losses when the fan is rotating.
The alternative would be to use a free-wheeling diode for each coil. That would:

Prolong the current decay of the coil being turned off,
Waste the entire energy stored in the magnetic field of the coil each time a coil turns of,
Add switching transients to the circuit, increasing the EMI.

The circuit, given its simplicity, is fairly clever. It does a reasonable job with the bare minimum number of components.
It is, in short, an oscillator with a rudimentary phase locked loop.
